# I'm having some issues working with parallel ssh

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I'm trying to figure out how to issue the same command to an entire cluster. I'm using parallel ssh, but I can't seem to get it to work right. When I try a command I get:

```
[1] 22:58:24 [FAILURE] user@host1.local Exited with error code 255
[2] 22:58:24 [FAILURE] user@host2.local Exited with error code 1
[3] 22:58:24 [FAILURE] user@host3.local Exited with error code 1
```

I looked up the error codes but I can't make sense of what is going on.

Comment: Can you `ssh` to each node (`host1`,`host2`,`host3`) by hand? Have you done `ssh-copy-id`? Did you set up passwordless `ssh` logins? How?

Comment: Yes I can get to each node manually. I haven't done copy-id. I TRIED to set up passwordless ssh and just failed miserably. I usually enter my password each time. Passwords are the same on each machine.

Comment: It looks like you are putting the `ssh` invocations in the background. Not a good strategy, until you get it to work. Try using the `-v` option to `ssh`, and, if you are putting `ssh` in the background, save `STDERR` to a file, via `ssh -v ..... 2>sshlog.$$`, then look at the `sshlog.*` files

Comment: I'm at work so I'll try this when I get home BUT I can't believe that this is this hard. All I'm trying to do is reduce the amount of typing I need to do to configure my cluster. I saw someone do it once. Is there a better approach I should be using?

Comment: IMHO, I would get passwordless SSH working to one node, figure out how i did it, and only after it works, do it to the others. Also, in your conrtolling script, log the command you are about to execute.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this the hard way? Try googling "using ssh to control cluster" and you will see many choices.

Comment: Puppet has a learning curve that I don't have time for and while I looked at clusterSSH, parallel SSH just looked easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to forget parallel ssh and use cssh instead:
http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-manage-multiple-ssh-sessions-using-cluster-ssh-and-pac-manager/